# Asp.Net Core performance issues when started under load

Tags: performance, asp.net-core, startup

I'm experiencing an issue with an asp.net core application that virtually hangs when started under load.  Once started, the application can handle the load no problem. It feels like initialization is happening for every concurrent request. Is anyone else experiencing similar behavior?

**test scenario:**

- start a test application that hits the service with 50 simultaneous tasks
- start the service
- notice the requests getting started, but extremely long delays before any start to finish and most will time out

As a temporary work around, I created middleware that throttles subsequent requests until the very first finishes. This effectively lets asp.net mvc initialize before processing the bulk of the requests. This particular app is asp.net core 1.1 (web api) with EF core.

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing the same issue, could you elaborate on the middleware you created ? I can't see a good way to implement it... And if you found the reason, I'd be really pleased to hear it ! Thanks

Comment: @Gouffe I posted my hack in an issue about asp.net core throughput: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1807#issuecomment-306329090

The issue got closed without really being resolved. I haven't been able to track it down to kestrel, ef core, or something else.  It "feels" like we're using some dependency with expensive initialization that isn't being mindful of concurrent requests.

Comment: Thanks for the link, unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem. I have an initialization problem, but also, at random times, the asp.net core process goes 100% cpu without any explication (yet). Thank you anyway, very interesting workaround !

Answer (score 1):

When using a real database located halfway across the country, I experience a good 900ms delay for the first request to my ASP.NET Core WebAPI. This is because it needs to get a connection pool established for use with connecting to said database, and I do not eagerly create a connection pool when running the service. Instead, it gets initialized lazily when I request a connection via a connection factory that is registered as a singleton in the services container.

Perhaps you're experiencing the same type of delay as you stated you're using Entity Framework Core, which is presumably backed by SQL Server. **Is a connection pool with the database being initiated lazily as part of this initial request?**

Try making a controller that does not have any dependencies that returns a vanilla `200 OK`. Assuming you do not have global filters that have expensive services to hydrate, you should see the baseline initialization performance of your web service.